# Сортировать массивы

Tags: java

Нужно создать метод, который объединяет буквы или числа из двух массивов в один.
Например есть два массива - `a` и `b`, которые должны быть записаны в один массив следующим образом - `[a[0],b[0],a[1],b[1] и т.д.]`

Второй метод должен делать тоже самое, только в метод добавляется переменная `n`, если переменная `n = 2`, то метод сортирует след образом - `[a[0],a[1],b[0],b[1] и т.д.]`

**Проблема**: метод просто выкидывает числа или иногда пустые места в массиве:

```
public static char [] smesch(char []i, char []q){
        String s = "";
        for(int k = 0; k < Math.min(i.length, q.length); k++){
            s += i[k] + q[k];
        }
        if(i.length < q.length){
            for(int k = i.length; k < q.length; k++){
                s += q[k];
            }
        }
        else{
            for(int k = q.length; k < i.length; k++){
                s += i[k];
            }
        }
        return s.toCharArray();
    }
```

Comment: "Помогите" или "сделайте за меня"? Если первое, то что именно не получается? Если второе, то не по адресу.

Comment: у меня есть код, но этот код почему -то записывает только один из массивов. На второе задание при каком -либо массиве с null выдает ошибку java.lang.NullPointerException , хотя в условие я написал чтобы выдавал второй не пустой массив.. И зачем сразу тему минусовать то ?

Comment: Добавьте код, который сделали.

Comment: Добавил выше ...

Answer (score 2):

Зачем столько циклов? Все проще...

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] x = {'1','3','5'};
        char[] y = {'2','4','6','7'};
        System.out.println(smesch(x, y));
    }

    public static char[] smesch(char[] arr1, char[] arr2) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length); i++) {
            if (arr1.length>i) sb.append(arr1[i]);
            if (arr2.length>i) sb.append(arr2[i]);
        }
        return sb.toString().toCharArray();
    }
}
```

Вывод : 1234567

Второй случай сложнее, я бы использовал в такой задаче итераторы. Выглядить это будет примерно так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Character[] x = {'1','3','5'};
    Character[] y = {'2','4','6','7'};
    System.out.println(smesch(x, y, 1));
    System.out.println(smesch(x, y, 2));
}

public static char[] smesch(Character[] arr1, Character[] arr2) {
    return smesch(arr1, arr2, 1);
}

public static char[] smesch(Character[] arr1, Character[] arr2, int n) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<Character> iterator1 = Arrays.asList(arr1).iterator();
    Iterator<Character> iterator2 = Arrays.asList(arr2).iterator();
    boolean isFirstIterator = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length + arr2.length; i++) {            
        if (i % n == 0) isFirstIterator = !isFirstIterator;            
        if (isFirstIterator && iterator1.hasNext()) sb.append(iterator1.next());
        else if (iterator2.hasNext()) sb.append(iterator2.next());
    }
    return sb.toString().toCharArray();
}
```

Из примитивных чаров я сделал ссылочные, потому как у массива итератора нет и нужно перекинуть его в лист. Для массива примитивных чаров эта задача таким способом не решается. Если там нужен принципиально именно массив примитивов, то способ конвертировать найдете в инете. В идеале, разумеется, прокинуть в метод коллекцию вроде листа, чтобы не выполнять преобразования совсем (если это допустимо для вас)

Comment: Да в том то и дело,что задачу нужно решить без "готовых" методов )

Comment: что значит без готовых?

Comment: Не особо еще пока разбираюсь в названиях, то есть как я решил путем плюс, минус и операторов:) Но , как оказалось, что-то я неправильно написал раз выдает иногда пустые массивы, иногда вообще цифры вместо букв :(

Comment: путем плюс-минус - это к индусам)) там все так пишут. если вас заставляют писать треш - лучше откажитесь. этого добра и так хватает

Comment: Это специально нужно так сдавать нам дабы мы понимали что происходит в коде, так говорит учитель:) Дальше, конечно же, этого не будет)

Comment: С таким успехом и просто `System.arraycopy` зашел бы. А не вот это, куча на куче. но почему то когда я дал ответ, то подумал. что ему не слияние нужно и удалил его. Но все равно. ему нужно без готового сделать, тупо на циклах, а это гемрно маленько и терять время не особо хотелось.

Comment: Можно и с System.arraycopy, я только не думаю, что там меньше кода будет. Все равно по массивам нужно как-то итерироваться, выбирая нужные элементы. Логика перебора разная и определяется переменной. А скопировать данные, когда они уже выбраны - задача не хитрая.