# Ограничение записи массива в массив

Tags: java, массивы

Пришлось немного подхимичить код чтобы при загрузке на сайт универа не одинаков был.. В общем где тут дописать чтобы при двух массивах с одним полем возвращалось не пустое значение, а значения этих двух полей?

```
                    public static char[] e(char[] q, char[] n){ 
                         int  perem = 0,
                         int lennn = q.length + n.length;
                    char[] ressu = new char[lennn];
                    for (int i = 0; i < lennn-2; i++) {
                        if (q.length > i) {
                            ressu[perem++] = q[i];
                        }
                        if (n.length > i) {
                            ressu[perem++] = n[i];
                        }
                    }
                    return ressu;
    }
```

Comment: А почему бы просто для слияния массивов в 1, не использовать `System.arraycopy` ? Там же и сортировку можно будет сделать, если понадобится.

Comment: @And, В том и дело, что надо что-то придумать дабы не использовать "библиотеки", а ограничить все в ручную.. нас так учат развивать мышление в университете. :(

Comment: Мышление нужно развивать библиотекам как-раз таки, чтобы в будущем иметь подход в 2 строчки, за место тучи циклов и кучи мусора. Их не просто так придумывают, нужно лезть внутрь, глубже и глубже, а не стоять на месте, разбираясь в циклах. не просто так их уже реализовали.

Comment: Понимаю, но к сожалению не могу ничего предъявить доценту. Вы же сами понимаете как это будет выглядеть, когда студент доказывает доценту, что он не прав :)

Comment: @And Посмотрите сверху, обновил ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам же [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1047381/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b) дали хороший ответ, а Вы его обкорнали.

1. Для цикла `for` необходимо ограничиваться не длиной массива `t` (почему именно `t`?! а что если `t` будет меньше массива `e`?!), а выбрать максимальную длину: `Math.max(t.length, e.length)`.
2. При добавлении элементов в новый массив проверять границы: `if (t.length > i) res[per++] = t[i]; if (e.length > i) res[per++] = e[i];`

**UPD:**

```
public static char[] f(char[] a1, char[] a2) {
    int len1 = a1 != null ? a1.length : 0;
    int len2 = a2 != null ? a2.length : 0;

    char[] res = new char[len1 + len2];

    for (int i = 0, p = 0, l = len1 > len2 ? len1 : len2; i < l; i++) {
        if (len1 > i) {
            res[p++] = a1[i];
        }
        if (len2 > i) {
            res[p++] = a2[i];
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Вывод:

```
char[] a1 = {'1', '3', '5', '7', '0'},
       a2 = {'4', '7', '9'};
System.out.println(f(a1, a2)); // 14375970
```

Comment: Да, Вы правы на счет того, что ответ хороший был дан, но я не могу использовать StringBuilder или .append.. ограничение в задании

Comment: @Str Ну не используйте. Создавайте новый массив, записывайте в него, но прочие условия и проверки то оставьте, обратите на них внимание.

Comment: @Str, `max` не нужно узнавать, вы уже его знаете, это у вас `t.length + e.length`, по этому `Math.max` можно убрать. Добавил полный код. Вам же нельзя готовые использовать, а уже с `Math.max`, согласились =) ЭЭЭХ.. вы =)

Comment: @And еще не согласился )) Так как новичек, то приходится собирать идеи и уже подгонять их как-то под задание..)) Сейчас попробую переделать код, там просто 2 метода, второй сложнее намного, прогоню через онлайн тест и если Вам интересно, то сообщу вышло ли :)

Comment: Все равно создает пустые поля метод, при обычном выводе не видно, а при онлайн тесте выводит именно разницу в два пустых поля

Comment: @Str, Да, мой косяк. Так-как. массив начинается с `0`, нужно отнимать `1`, следуя тому, что `a1` начинается от `0` до `4`, в итоге `a1.length` будет равен `5`, то нужно сделать `-1` чтобы было `4`, так-как, начало от `0-4`, со вторым массивом происходит ровно тоже самое. По этому нужно сделать `len-2`  в цикле и все будет норм.

Comment: @Str @And У Вас заработало? Я всё же за `max` в условии. Потому как два массива мы пробегаем параллельно друг другу и интересует нас именно максимальная длина, а не сумма. А для массива-результата у нас отдельный счётчик `per`.

Comment: @And Да, но вот проблема при онлайн тесте, когда у каждого массива по одному полю - возвращает пустой массив, хотя поля со значениями.. Или второй массив равен null, то вместо того чтобы вернуть массив со значением, он возвращает 0 не смотря на то, что прописано возвращать со значением.. Сижу вот и думаю как исправить

Comment: @Str, при каком онлайн тесте? Задача не понятна. Показывайте, что вы там тестите. И Что должно быть в итоге.

Comment: @And тестю на сайте университета, там должно каждое задание быть протестировано и если все задачи из стека задач за неделю(недель всего 9 - это 9 баллов к экзамену если все правильные) прошли тест, то автоматом прибавляется балл к экзамену :) Вы не будете против если я его вам в личные сообщения скину дабы меня потом за плагиат не отругали своего же кода?:)

Comment: @Str Я обновил функцию в ответе. Можете проверить её. Должна учитывать и пустые массивы и null. Мой совет - начинайте пробовать разбираться в этом коде. Строчка за строчкой, оператора за оператором. Что и за что отвечает, какие функции выполняет. Надо разобраться с самого начала, вот хотя бы начиная с этой же функции, иначе далеко не уедете. Ну и ссылку на тесты можете мне тоже скинуть, но мне чисто из любопытства.

Comment: @justcvb К сожалению ссылку дать не могу, т.к. там нужно заходить под своим id, который все университетский, с которого можно делать все, от регистрации на экзамены, отмены экзаменов, смены адреса и прочее.. Я бы мог скидывать логи, но вижу, что тут нет функции личных смс на форуме, что печально... За код спасибо, попробую вписать в свой, там у меня 2 метода просто, поэтому немного нужно менять. На счет разбираться в коде, не поверите, но двое суток сижу не отходя, просто нет того, кто хорошо может обьяснить простые вопросы , которые не всегда в гугле найдешь

Comment: @justcvb,, у вас будет таже проблема - `max` даст `5`, а массив начинается с `0` и заканчивается на `4`. + 1 пустой элемент, еще проблема может быть из за того. что `len1` и `len2` не отнято `1` длина массива не равна их порядковым номерам.

Comment: @And Да, ты прав, массивы при записи в общий массив только по одному элементу выводят - ничего...

Comment: Ко всему, ему не нужны готовые решения, через `Math.max`, по этому я написал без ее использования. Ладно. как хотите. Мой вариaнт был верный, за исключением, нужно было отнять у длин массивов еще по `1`. То-есть, от общей уже отняли. останется отнять у `2х` которые проверяем `>i`.

Comment: @And я решаю по твоему методу без Math.max ... но немного не понимаю как сделать без дополнительного условия if при массивах с одним полем, чтобы считало правильно

Comment: @Str, обновляй вопрос со всеми подробностями иначе это раздуется в комментах ненужно общаться как в чате перенесут...

Comment: @Str @And Откровенно говоря, не понимаю о чём вы. Вычитать единицу не нужно, потому что проверка на строго меньше. А `i < Math.max(len1, len2)` можно заменить на `i < (len1 > len2 ? len1 : len2)` или создать отдельную переменную, инициализируя её максимальным значением. Обновил ответ. И да, эту дискуссию лучше вести в чате.

Comment: @And , justcvb я обновил тему, можно ли сделать с моим кодом что-то? Ибо мне его рассказывать нужно еще будет, а там где обновленный for () еще сложновато для меня :( Не совсем понимаю что там происходит

Answer (score 0):

Условие продолжения цикла в `for` - `i < lennn-2` очевидно неправильное. Надо:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < q.length || i < n.length; i++) {
```

*Демонстрационный* пример на JavaScript:

```js
function merge(q, n) {
  var ressu = [];
  ressu.length = q.length + n.length;
  var perem = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < q.length || i < n.length; i++) {
    if (q.length > i) {
      ressu[perem++] = q[i];
    }
    if (n.length > i) {
      ressu[perem++] = n[i];
    }
  }
  return ressu;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(merge([1], [2])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(merge([1,2,3], [10,20,30,40,50])));
```

Comment: Заменил, все равно ошибка сохранилась :(

Comment: @Str Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: Перепроверил, все правильно.. все равно при char[] q = {'1'};
            char[] n = {'2'}; ошибка осталась :(

Comment: @Str Какая ошибка, я должен угадать?

Comment: которая выше описана в теме... метод возвращает пустой массив если два записываемые в него массива имеют по одному полю

Comment: @Str Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код. Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в ответе.

Comment: А js то тут причем вообще?

Comment: @And Тоже начинается на "j". Какая разница? "You can write FORTRAN code in any language."

Comment: Какая разница и в правду, давайте в метках js ,будем java писать и наоборот, гениально!

Comment: @And Давайте не будем делать из меток культа. "Метка не догма, а руководство к действию."

Comment: @Str да у Вас там похоже либо ошибка в тестах, либо Вы что-то не так понимаете. Попробуйте уже обратиться к своему преподавателю, пусть объясняет, ну или к одногруппникам.

Comment: @And Сударь, Вы случайно скатились в хамский тон. Мне не нужны никакие справки. Я делаю то, что считаю правильным и допустимым. Код в моем ответе - чудесный. P.S. Кто такая "разбериха"?

Comment: Вопрос же про алгоритмы, а не про фичи JS. В принципе, ответ можно дать на любом языке, хоть на псведокоде. Но тут ТС, кажется, не заметил, что язык в ответе другой. @Igor, не могли бы вы дописать текстом, что это JS и надо не копировать, а вникать в суть алгоритма?